# MVC 5 - jQuery DatePicker changed date - postback to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying find a way to make an Ajax form postback when either the datepicker selected date is changed, or use a hidden textbox and use the onchanged method, but can't find a way to do it (change the date in a datepicker and then hit a submit button and it gets back the controller...)

View

```
<div class="panel-body">
    @Using (Ajax.BeginForm(Nothing, "Calendar/DateChanged", Nothing, New AjaxOptions With {.HttpMethod = "POST"}, New With {.id = "SelectDateForm"}))
        @<div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div id="datepicker"></div>

        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.Current_Date, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", New With {.id = "inputMaintDate", .class = "form-control", .type = "date", .onchange = "SelectDateForm.submit();"})
    </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                 <button id="LoginButton" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Save</button>

             </div>


    </div>

    End Using

</div>
```

Scripts

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#inputMaintDate').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: $('SelectDateForm').serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
            }
        });
    });
});


 $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        altField: '#inputMaintDate'
        //inline: true
                });
        });
```

Controller

```
  <HttpPost()>
    Function DateChanged(vModal As CalendarModels)
        Try
            Dim vDate As Date = vModal.Current_Date
            Return ModalValidation(vDate.ToString)
        Catch ex As Exception
            EmailError(ex)
            Return SystemError()
        End Try
    End Function
```

============ EDIT =====================

By adding an onchange event to the datepicker

```
<div id="datepicker" onchange="SelectDateForm.submit();"></div>
```

It now posts back to the controller DateChanged function, but instead of sending back a JavaScriptResult it asks the user if they want to run or save DateChangedxxxxxx.js. Had this issue when we moved to .NET 4.6 and adding jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js fixed it

Big sigh!

What is the main difference between posting back from a button or using a control onchange event?

Comment: The main difference between `onchange="SelectDateForm.submit()` and `$(selector).change(function() { $.ajax(); })` is the former is doing a standard form submission while the later is doing an AJAX post. Standard form submissions will cause the browser to navigate while AJAX does not. The exact behavior you see is hard to explain without seeing more of your code and/or the rendered html.

Comment: Thank you for your reply - I did get there, but it was more by trial and error than scientific reasoning :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out

For the datepicker

```
<div id="datepicker" onchange="onChangeCalender();"></div>
```

and the script

```
 function onChangeCalender() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("DateChanged", "Calendar")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#SelectDateForm').serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
        }
    });
}
```

Now it hits the controller, with the correct selected date AND returns the script correctly - Yeh!!